# Tiles map server - How to provide the same tiles on lower zoom?

Tags: openlayers

I have my own map server defined like below. This is one layer, but have 4 layers for other zooms. Unfortunately for zoom lower then 8 I don't have tile images. Is possible to make zoom out lower than 8 work using **the same tiles** (as for zoom 8) somehow ? If yes, what can I do, where to start ?

```
var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: 'EPSG:2180',
    wrapX: true,
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
        origin: // ...
        resolutions: resolutions,
        tileSize: [256, 256],
    }),
    tileUrlFunction: function(coord){
        if(coord == null) return null;
        // ...
    }
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: source
    }), ...],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({         
        center: ol.proj.transform([20.9207687,52.2328546], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 8,
        maxZoom: 14,
        // minZoom: 8
    })
});
```

Comment: You can set a minZoom option in the tilegrid https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_tilegrid_TileGrid-TileGrid.html

Comment: Thank You. It works. Maybe You can make this comment as answer, so i could accept it ;)